# Switch off or on ethernet connection

Tags: android, wifi, ethernet

I am programming an app for a specific tablet, which can use an ethernet connection using either a cradle or a USB-to-Ethernet adapter. It all works fine, except it switches off the WiFi as soon as I connect the ethernet.

I can call `startUsingNetworkFeature(1, "p2p")` to switch on the WiFi again, but it will result in losing the IP address on the ethernet connection (as I see using `ip a l` in `adb shell`).

Is there some way to have both WiFi and a live ethernet connection (on a physical different net), or being able to switch from one to the other?

It is OK to use reflection, as I am in complete control of the app and the hardware it runs on. It is not OK to root the device, as it will void our guarantee.

Comment: Ask the tablet manufacturer.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did, to no avail...

Comment: You can't have two live connections open at the same time as long as you don't have two network cards...

Comment: @Manu I do, in fact, I have 3: wired LAN, the WiFi and the 3G